# How can I find the 4th image shown in my iFrame and display it on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```
 img[i] = document.images[5].src;
```

Currently recites the 4th image of a loaded document.
I want to set this document to a specific url.

Because document returns an object, I've tried replacing this with iFrame, and setting the iFrame src to the url I need the image from.
See:

```
 iframe = document.getElementId("URL");

 doc= iframe.contentWindow.document;

 img[i] = doc.images[5].src;
```

With the html including the iframe URL (obviously).
Didn't work. I'm at stage one. How can I find the 4th image shown in my iFrame and display it on my webpage?

Comment: `document.images[5].src;` - that's actually the 6th image in a document. Is the iframe source in the same domain as the main document?

Comment: @JaromandaX, No it is not in the same domain. If it was , would that change things?

Comment: different domain means no access due to `same origin policy`. Exact same message was given to you in the last question you asked about iFrames

Comment: Maybe `document.getElementId(...)` is just a posting typo?

Comment: Further to @charlietfl comment, if it was in the same domain, it would work as you posted it

Comment: @JaromandaX, so different domain is not possible?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @charlietfl not asking you. thats not valid

Comment: actually @charlietfl's link is valid

Comment: how can it not be valid when it's produced by one of the major browser vendors and clearly tells you that window in iframe is read only for cross domain?

Comment: @Jaromanda X it's valid but not sound.

Comment: looking forward to hearing how it isn't sound. Google that term , will find many hundreds of posts on this site...and all over the web telling you the same thing

Comment: @JaromandaX Can you let charlietfl know thanks for spamming reported for harrasment and spam

Comment: thanks @MaxGillard ... that last one gave me a good laugh

Comment: In the words of Hans Shultz .... I know nothing, nothing

Comment: Hey you need to create proxy server and load the page in your proxy and add Js which will read the forth image from the page and call main page function with that url :) I have do like that way in past.

Comment: @Mitul thank you Mitul, will try this.

Comment: @MaxGillard let me know if you need any help